# AutoDesk Forge Viewer API Throwing error when opening a second viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am having issues with the way my viewer is integrated inside my web application. On the first instance of running my viewer I don't experience any problems. See, there are many different viewers on each page of my application. However, when I want to open a second viewer, I get the standard console logs ...

> "THREE.WebGLRenderer 71 WebGLRenderer.js:29:12
> WEBGL_debug_renderer_info is deprecated in Firefox and will be removed. Please use RENDERER. WebGLRenderer.js:232:30
> WebGL Renderer: ANGLE (Intel(R) HD Graphics 400 Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0, D3D11-27.20.100.8854) WebGLRenderer.js:237:20
> WebGL Vendor: Google Inc. (Intel)"

... Followed by the error:

```
Rendering to a canvas that was resized to zero. If you see this message you may be accidentally leaking a viewer instance. ErrorCode:14. Logger.js:188:18
_reportError Logger.js:188
beginScene RenderContext.js:607
initialize Viewer3DImpl.js:368
initialize Viewer3D.js:608
initialize GuiViewer3D.js:59
start Viewer3D.js:374
showViewer showViewer.js:72
(Async: promise callback)
K envinit.js:718
showViewer showViewer.js:68
updateStatus showViewer.js:11
getStatus showViewer.js:48
i x12:2
fireWith x12:2
A x12:4
c x12:4
(Async: EventHandlerNonNull)
send x12:4
ajax x12:4
ajax xtrue:4
getStatus showViewer.js:37
showViewer showViewer.js:97
anonymous Autodesk-Forge-Viewer--testing--update--Forge-Viewer-.js:89
v x12:6
B x12:6
v x12:6
run_without_catching_not_ready x12:6
v x12:6
value x12:6
r x12:6
value x12:6
n x12:6
n x12:6
traceSpan x12:6
n x12:6
(Async: setTimeout handler)
exports x12:13
R x12:6
value x12:6
value x12:6
value x12:6
value x12:6
value x12:6
initialize x12:6
value x12:6
autorun_top x12:6
value x12:6
run x12:6
value x12:6
value x12:6
value x12:6
value x12:6
value x12:6
run_once x12:6
run x12:6
value x12:6
value x12:6
value x12:6
value x12:6
value x12:6
value x12:6
value x12:6
exports x12:6
value x12:6
value x12:6
```

Does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening? At first I thought "... accidentally leaking a viewer ..." error meant that the html element wasn't closed, but that wasn't the case. I'm at a loss, I'm not sure what the issue is. Here is my viewer code:

```
    function showViewer(){
    let viewer;
    let options = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction',
        api: 'derivativeV2',
        getAccessToken: function(onTokenReady) {
            var token = viewerAccessToken;
            var timeInSeconds = 3600;
            onTokenReady(token, timeInSeconds);
        }
    };
    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
        let htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
        viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv);
        instance.data.viewer = viewer;
        let startedCode = viewer.start();
        viewer.setTheme("light-theme");
        viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.CustomDocumentBrowser").then(() => {
            viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore");
            viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui");
        });
        if (startedCode > 0) {
            console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
            $("#loadingStatus").html("Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.");
            return;
        }
        console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');
    });
    let documentId = `urn:` + viewerUrn;
    let derivativeId = `urn:` + instance.derivativeUrn;
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
    function onDocumentLoadSuccess(viewerDocument) {
        let defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
        viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
    }
    function onDocumentLoadFailure() {
        console.error('Failed fetching Forge manifest');
        $("#loadingStatus").html("Failed fetching Forge manifest.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is often caused by CSS layout. When you try and instantiate the viewer inside a `<div>` that either has a zero width and height, or has `display` set to `none`, the viewer would fail to initialize its WebGL rendering pipeline.

Here's a simple Forge app that initializes two viewers on a single page: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-simple-viewer-nodejs/tree/sample/multiple-viewers (note that the code is in a branch called `sample/multiple-viewers`).

Comment: Thanks! It turned out to be a mix of a styling issue and the fact that I needed to introduce logic so that every new viewer has a different ID (you see, there can be dozens of viewers depending on which page you're on...) however for some reason document browser only works on the first viewer (but the second viewer will work if you don't use the first document browser). I'll keep ironing this out :) Thank you

Comment: out of curiosity, are you aware if it's possible to pass arguments to an extension? For example, my viewer has a unique timestamp attached to it, I would like to pass it to my extension 'customDocumentBrowser' so that it can make appropriate ID's with timestamps :) Thanks so much, you are very helpful, I appreciate it!

Comment: Happy to help :) Take a look at my blog post https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-extensions-tips-and-tricks-or-treats. There's a section on how one can pass options to extensions.

Comment: Hey I am having issues accessing my object inside the extension. I am getting undefined. Is there anything I need to know about the extension constructor?

Comment: Options are passed to the extension by the viewer as a second argument of the constructor. First argument is the instance of the viewer itself.